# css, using rotate and jquery to initial position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation

I use a class, that make a picture rotate.

This class looks like that

```
.zodiac_rotate {
    -webkit-animation:spin 15s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 15s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 15s linear infinite;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

I also tried to do that rotate using jquery but in css I've seen that it is more fluid so I decided to do it in css only.

Now, using jquery I would like to stop the rotate when the mouse is over the picture. I did a small javascript and it works fine :

```
 $('#zodiac').hover(function(){
     $(this).removeClass('zodiac_rotate');
      },function(){
          $(this).addClass('zodiac_rotate');
       })
```

The trouble I have is with the position, I would like that when we mouse over the image, it stay at its position, when I remove the class, it goes like the original position, so the effect is not so fine.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: when u mouse over it,do u want to slow down to original position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`animation-play-state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) for that

```
$('#zodiac').on('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).css('-webkit-animation-play-state','paused');
    $(this).css('animation-play-state','paused');
});

$('#zodiac').on('mouseout', function () {
    $(this).css('-webkit-animation-play-state','running');
    $(this).css('animation-play-state','running');
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/5DwLW/)

Comment: verry cool, all works fine, thank you so much for the help, I appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Do rotate with jquery something like this:

```
$('#zodiac').hover(function(){
  $(this).css('transform','rotate(0deg)');
});
```